# how to count the number of items contains in list in C# or linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to count Number of count that the list contains the string.

I don't want list count.
I don't want the list's particular string count.'

I just want the count of number of items contains with particular string in list.

In Linq or ordinary c# any way

```
 Hashtable newlist  = new Hashtable();
      newlist = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["Userlogin"] as Hashtable;
count = newlist.Count(s => newlist.Contains(sKey));

foreach (DictionaryEntry item1 in newlist)
{
    if (newlist.Contains(sKey))
    {
         count = count + 1;
    }
}
```

newlist is a Hashtable

Comment: No offense, but your question is rather hard to read or understand. Do you mean :  sKey can be present many times in each element of newlist. For example, if skey = "the", and newlist contains "the rabbit is the fastest" and "the wolve is the wolve", you wanna get "4" as result?

Comment: may be my question is not understandable but 2 of people understood what i need. but you people quickly close my question. any way thank you...

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can understand your question

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "a","b","a","c","c" };

var counts = list.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());

var cntC = counts["c"];
var cntA = counts["a"];
```

Comment: It shows hashtable does not contains the definiton Where, groupby.

Comment: @Thiyagarajan Your question and what you store in hashtable is unclear. So I can not give a better answer.

Comment: sorry i'm bad in english. i want to count the number of list.contain(string)<-- want count of this. if any duplicate in hashtable it should show 2 or 3. have u understand.

Comment: @Thiyagarajan, But at least you can show some codes how you store your data. Hashtable contains KeyValue pairs, What is your key, what is your value? If you want to count the keys, you don't need anything, since keys must be unique. Either they exist(count=1) or not(count=0).

Comment: Hashtable newlist  = new Hashtable();
newlist = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["Userlogin"] as Hashtable;                                                         if (newlist.Contains(sKey))
                    {
                        count = count + 1;
                    }

Comment: @Thiyagarajan As I said Keys are **unique**.  `if (newlist.Contains(sKey))  return 1; else return 0;`

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
count = newlist.AsQueryable().Where(s => s.Contains(sKey)).Count();
```

Do I understand correctly what you are trying to get?

Comment: It shows hashtable does not contains the definiton Where

Comment: Oops missed that part :) slap an AsQueryable()

Answer (score 0):

Something like that

```
var newlist = new string[5] {"qqq","wwqww","wqwww","wqwww","wqwwxw"};

var count = newlist.Count(s => s.Contains("x"));
```

Output

```
count = 1
```

Comment: Where is not working for hashtable.. It shows hashtable does not contains the definiton Where, groupby.   Hashtable does not contain method for count